# Declaring function argument types

Tags: typescript

I have a variable of a known type `T` with some members of type `something | null`.
I have checked those members type by an `if` statement and then have passed them to a function .

If I set the function argument to type `T` I will have to setup the `if` statements again even though I already know that they are `not null`.

Only solutions I can think of is to use `@ts-ignore`, cast to desired type `(data2.player as Player)` or set the function argument type to `any`.

I have tried a fourth option which doesn't work for some reason.

```
interface Player {
    health: number;
    position: [number, number];
}

interface Data {
    level: number;
    player: Player | null;
}

function logPlayer(data2: Data & {player: Player}) {
    console.log(`Health: ${data2.player.health}`);
    console.log(`X: ${data2.player.position[0]}, Y: ${data2.player.position[1]}`);
}

function checkFunction(data: Data) {
    if (!data.player) return; // At this point data.player is definitely not null
    console.log(`You are on level ${data.level}`);
    logPlayer(data); // 'Data' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Data & { player: Player; }'
    // ...
}
```

Any solution or even helpful tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use `function checkFunction(data: Data & {player?:Player})`

Comment: What do you mean by "I have tried a fourth option which doesn't work for some reason."?

Comment: I just miscounted the number of solutions I have provided. I mean the solution presented in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
function logPlayer(player: Player) {
    console.log(`Health: ${player.health}`);
    console.log(`X: ${player.position[0]}, Y: ${data2.player.position[1]}`);
}

function checkFunction(data: Data) {
    if (!data.player) return;
    console.log(`You are on level ${data.level}`);
    logPlayer(data.player);
    // ...
}
```

Or if you wanted to keep the `logPlayer` function as is, you could create a custom typeguard:

```
function checkFunction(data: Data) {
    if (!hasPlayer(data)) return;
    console.log(`You are on level ${data.level}`);
    logPlayer(data);
    // ...
}

function hasPlayer(data: Data): data is Data & {player: Player} {
    return Boolean(data.player);
}
```

Comment: I'm actually not sure why your code doesn't work, because typescript now knows that player is not null...

Comment: Is there any way to make the hasPlayer function async?

Comment: @Orion It doesn't need to be async. You can call it without issue inside async functions though, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I have simplified the code too much so the problem is not visible from the provided code but my Player object has a special async function to check if the object isn't null, so I am asking if there is any way to make `async function hasPlayer()`.

Comment: Don't think it can be async. Also, I don't think it's a good idea to check if a player isn't null asynchronously. `null` is a value inside the program's memory, there's no need for it to be async.

Comment: @Orion Feel free to use the first code snipped though, it makes more sense for `logPlayer` to take a `Player` instead of `Data` anyway